# bytes of file download appear as plain text instead of as actual attachment

Tags: jsf, download, seam2

I think I have put all the pieces together to provide download file. Instead, below code is writing byte array on browser itself. I am sure the byte [] do not have any problem as I used FileOutputStream earlier to generate the excel file.

```
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)fc.getExternalContext().getResponse();

    InputStream templateInputStream=null;

    try {
        templateInputStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(SOME_PATH);
        if(templateInputStream==null) {
            throw new WebException("Template not found at: "+SOME_PATH);
        }

        byte[] suppData= ExcelRenderer.render(templateInputStream, data);

        response.reset();
        response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=\""+REPORT_FILE_NAME+"\"");

        response.getOutputStream().write(suppData);

        response.flushBuffer();
        fc.responseComplete();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{

        if (templateInputStream!=null){
            templateInputStream.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try adding a space after the semicolon in attachment;filename?

Comment: Have you checked, using the browser developer tools, that the headers are received by the browser?

Comment: `response.reset();` You wrote something to the response already?  Yeah...you can't just reset it always.

Comment: @BalusC: congrats for the 500K rep points!

Comment: Reponse header-Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="Reports.xlsx"
Content-Type:application/octet-stream
Date:Thu, 14 Aug 2014 15:37:42 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Powered-By:JSF/1.2

Comment: @BCartololess: Yes, I tried, but still the same result.

Comment: @developerwjk- I didn't have that initially. But again, I have removed it, it didn't help.